# Should a keyword field be an array or a single string?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm an ElasticSearch newbie so this is a pretty basic question.

If I map a field as a keyword in the index should the document contain an array of strings for that field? Or one string with all the keywords separated by a space?

If my index looks like this (Keyword is what we're interested in):

```
{
  "esidx_j_cv" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "j_cv" : {
        "properties" : {
          "Id" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "Keyword" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "Name" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

should a document look like this:

```
{
    "_index" : "esidx_j_cv",
    "_type" : "j_cv",
    "_id" : "2fab7349-c13f-447a-95fa-984df6836c14",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "Id" : "2fab7349-c13f-447a-95fa-984df6836c14",
      "Name" : "Jim Bloggs",
      "Keyword" : [
        "San",
        "Andreas",
        "Fault",
        "California"
      ]
    }
 }
```

or like this:

```
  {
    "_index" : "esidx_j_cv",
    "_type" : "j_cv",
    "_id" : "2fab7349-c13f-447a-95fa-984df6836c14",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "Id" : "2fab7349-c13f-447a-95fa-984df6836c14",
      "Name" : "Jim Bloggs",
      "Keyword" : "San Andreas Fault California"
     }
   }
```

Thanks,

Adam.

Comment: Your document can look any one of these. :)

Comment: Here `keyword` means just a field name or do you want to store `keyword` type values into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an array would be the most idiomatic and would be my recommendation. You can query it like this (this query will actually work with either option):

```
GET index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "Keyword": "California" 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all for the responses.